# How can I count the rows returned from a stored-procedure that returns a table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to count how many rows returned by a stored-procedure which returns a simple table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return `@@ROWCOUNT` as either an output parameter or second result set.

Or add another column to the one resultset using a COUNT..OVER construct

```
...
COUNT(*) OVER () AS RowCount
...
```

Or read it in the client code eg [`DataTable.Rows.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135388.aspx)